# How do I use jquery to make a click on a link post to a php script with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a database of members which I need to be able to click on an alphabetical character link or button, pass that character to an ajax event and run a script with the character as an option, something like getResults?char=A on a regular submitted form.

```
<form>

<p>
<a href="#" name="char" class="switchChar" value="A" id="A">A</a>
<a href="#" name="char" class="switchChar" value="B" id="B">B</a>
</p>

<div id="Results">Results Div</div>

</form>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // $(document).on('click','.switchChar',function()
    $('a.switchChar').click(function() {

      var DATA=$(this).val();
      var data=(DATA);
      var CHAR=$(this).attr('char');
      $("#Results").html( "" );
      var dataString = 'char='+ data;

      $.ajax({
        url: "getResults.php", /* Will add this later */
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
          $("#Results").html(data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `var DATA=$(this).val();` or `var CHAR=$(this).attr('char');` and `var data=(DATA);`

use `.attr('value');` its 'a' element not 'input'(`.val()`)

or use `$(this).html();` for get letter inside `<a></a>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.switchChar').click(function() {
      var data=$(this).attr('value'); //this 'a' element (not 'input'), 'value' -> attribute
      $("#Results").html("");
      var dataString ='char='+ data ; 
     console.log(dataString)
      $.ajax({
           url: "getResults.php", /* Will add this later */
           type: "post",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
              $("#Results").html(data);
           }

      });
   });
  });
```

Comment: Thx that works. I had changed it to using var DATA=$(this).val(); and it was posting but not passing the value. Now it works correctly.